# remove-item network location using invoke-command on remote computer fails

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

Running the following powershell command

```
invoke-computer -computer computer -scriptblock{remove-item -force \\otherpc\backup_dump\TEST\*}
```

I receive the error

> An object at the specified path
>   \otherpc\backup_dump\TEST\ does not
>   exist.

But when I run it locally it works, I suspect there is something to do with scope here but I'm not sure of that, any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

This is the classic CredSSP issue. Check this:
[Mutli-Hop authentication using CredSSP](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230)

Comment: Your article is great, but is there a way to avoid typing a password each time you issue a remote command? (similar as ssh-agent on ssh)

Comment: you can create a credential object using Get-Credential and use the -Credential parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the local path (C:\otherpc\backup_dump\TEST*) instead of the UNC path?

Answer (score 0):

A long shot but maybe your (unquoted) path \otherpc... is interpreted as a local path? Have you tried quoting the path, like so:

`... remove-item -force "\\otherpc\backup_dump..."`

Answer (score 0):

Prepend filesystem:: to the UNC path.

`invoke-computer -computer computer -scriptblock{remove-item -force filesystem::\\otherpc\backup_dump\TEST\*}`

See http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/11/05/pstip-using-unc-paths-when-working-with-powershell-providers/